# How to find angles of a triangle inside a circle given a perpendicular tangent line?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image: Link to circle problem, sorry can't embed yet]

As the title says, I'm having trouble with tangent perpendicular lines and circles in triangles. I was given the problem linked above for practice & given the answer, but I am still stumped on it.

I was only able to solve for angle a, which equals 80, since 60 + 40 + a = 180.

The given answers to the equation are:

- Angle a = 80
- Angle b = 40
- Angle c = 60

I'm more confused on how to solve for angle b & c in the first place. I would also greatly appreciate a breakdown of the steps of solving this problem if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $O$ is the center, what is $\angle OAD$? Also do you know angle subtended by a chord at the center is double of angle subtended at the circumference? Using these two information, you can find $\angle B$ and $\angle C$.

Comment: If you look up the Inscribed Angle Theorem and the Tangent-Chord Theorem, put together they say that $\angle EAC\cong\angle B$ and $\angle DAB\cong\angle E$ because in each congruence the two angles intercept the same arc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the angles in the tangent, they are incribed angles too, the same as c and b

Improving what i said, the angle c = the angle 60 and the angle 40 = to the angle b, because the angle formed by the tangent and a segment passing through the circuference twice it is an inscribed angle.

Comment: Please use 
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
in to format math expressions properly.

Answer (score 1):

Illustration just for one angle, $\beta$:

[image]

\begin{align} 
\angle EAO&=\angle OFA=90^\circ
,\\
\angle ABC&=\tfrac12\angle AOC=
\angle AOF=\angle FOC=\beta
,\\
\angle FAO&=90^\circ-\beta 
,\\
\angle EAF&=\angle EAO-\angle FAO
=90^\circ-(90^\circ-\beta)=
\beta
.
\end{align}

The reasoning for the other angle ($\gamma)$ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

One of Euclid's propositions..

*In a circumscribed  triangle the angle between a chord and tangent at a point equals the angle in the alternate segment.*

That determines where the angles $ 40^0, 60^0 $ should go.